# autodesk-platform-services aps-iot issue: heatmap failed

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I cloned the Autodesk Data Visualization service, `aps-iot-extensions-demo-master`; I found the Node.js in VSCode showed that "the file extension loaded into the viewer is not supported, try a different file". After follow previous similar question I solved this issue by setting `const APS_MODEL_VIEW = ''` and changing `getDefaultGeometry()` to `getDefaultGeometry(true)`.

Another issue exist: I just replaced `APS_CLIENT_ID`, `APS_CLIENT_SECRET`, `APS_MODEL_URN` and `APS_MODEL_VIEW`; the URN and GUID are obtained through a Model Derivative API. The source Revit file was translated to .svf file. However, the heatmap is not visualized in the Web and there is no error existing in the console. The sensor location (x,y,z) are all set to be included in the Room bounds. The Model Browser in Viewer can also see "Rooms" element.

Interesting, the console will not show error about "sensor do not within the Room bounds" when I put them outside the room. Maybe the inter-connect for sensor and room is not right? Do I need to try .svf2? If anyone can help, I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The `aps-iot-extensions-demo` doesn't use the default way to initialize the heapmaps via `ModelStructureInfo`.

But ..., I cannot reproduce this issue with your test model. The heatmap shows fine on my side. So, please check your `services/iot.mocked.js` and `public/config.js`.

However, for some reason, the above way doesn't work for specific models.

And, in some cases, the rooms in the model are within another room like the one below, for example, which will cause room 2 not to have a device mapped.

```
/**
 *  ----------------
 * |                |
 * |                |
 * |      Room 1    |
 * |        ________|
 * |       | Room 2 |
 *  -----------------
 */
```

Here is the modified code using the `ModelStructureInfo` and added some extra logic to handle the room collision case:

```js
/// import * as Autodesk from "@types/forge-viewer";
import { UIBaseExtension } from './BaseExtension.js';
import { findNearestTimestampIndex } from './HistoricalDataView.js';
import { SensorHeatmapsPanel } from './SensorHeatmapsPanel.js';
export const SensorHeatmapsExtensionID = 'IoT.SensorHeatmaps';
export class SensorHeatmapsExtension extends UIBaseExtension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
        this.panel = undefined;
        this._surfaceShadingData = undefined;
        this.onChannelChanged = undefined;
        this.getSensorValue = this.getSensorValue.bind(this);
    }
    onDataViewChanged(oldDataView, newDataView) {
        this.updateChannels();
        this.createHeatmaps();
    }
    onCurrentTimeChanged(oldTime, newTime) { this.updateHeatmaps(); }
    onCurrentChannelChanged(oldChannelID, newChannelID) { this.updateHeatmaps(); }
    getSensorValue(surfaceShadingPoint, sensorType) {
        if (!this.dataView || !this.currentTime || !this.currentChannelID) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        const sensor = this.dataView.getSensors().get(surfaceShadingPoint.id);
        if (!sensor) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        const channel = this.dataView.getChannels().get(this.currentChannelID);
        if (!channel) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        const samples = this.dataView.getSamples(surfaceShadingPoint.id, this.currentChannelID);
        if (!samples) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        const fractionalIndex = findNearestTimestampIndex(samples.timestamps, this.currentTime, true);
        const index1 = Math.floor(fractionalIndex);
        const index2 = Math.ceil(fractionalIndex);
        if (index1 !== index2) {
            const value = samples.values[index1] + (samples.values[index2] - samples.values[index1]) * (fractionalIndex - index1);
            return (value - channel.min) / (channel.max - channel.min);
        }
        else {
            const value = samples.values[index1];
            return (value - channel.min) / (channel.max - channel.min);
        }
    }
    async createHeatmaps() {
        if (this.isActive()) { // TODO: update @types/forge-viewer
            const channelID = this.currentChannelID;
            await this._setupSurfaceShading(this.viewer.model);

            let levels = this._surfaceShadingData.children.map(data => data.id);
            this._dataVizExt.renderSurfaceShading(levels, channelID, this.getSensorValue);
        }
    }
    async updateHeatmaps() {
        if (this.isActive()) { // TODO: update @types/forge-viewer
            const channelID = this.currentChannelID;
            if (!this._surfaceShadingData) {
                await this._setupSurfaceShading(this.viewer.model);

                let levels = this._surfaceShadingData.children.map(data => data.id);
                this._dataVizExt.renderSurfaceShading(levels, channelID, this.getSensorValue);
            }
            else {
                this._dataVizExt.updateSurfaceShading(this.getSensorValue);
            }
        }
    }
    updateChannels() {
        if (this.dataView && this.panel) {
            this.panel.updateChannels(this.dataView);
        }
    }
    async load() {
        await super.load();
        this.panel = new SensorHeatmapsPanel(this.viewer, 'heatmaps', 'Heatmaps', {});
        this.panel.onChannelChanged = (channelId) => {
            if (this.onChannelChanged) {
                this.onChannelChanged(channelId);
            }
        };
        console.log(`${SensorHeatmapsExtensionID} extension loaded.`);
        return true;
    }
    unload() {
        var _a;
        super.unload();
        (_a = this.panel) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.uninitialize();
        this.panel = undefined;
        console.log(`${SensorHeatmapsExtensionID} extension unloaded.`);
        return true;
    }
    activate() {
        var _a;
        super.activate();
        (_a = this.panel) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.setVisible(true);
        this.onDataViewChanged(undefined, undefined);
        return true;
    }
    deactivate() {
        var _a;
        super.deactivate();
        (_a = this.panel) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.setVisible(false);
        this._dataVizExt.removeSurfaceShading();
        return true;
    }
    onToolbarCreated() {
        this.createToolbarButton('iot-heatmaps-btn', 'IoT Heatmaps', 'https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/heat-map.png'); // <a href="https://icons8.com/icon/8315/heat-map">Heat Map icon by Icons8</a>
    }

    async _setupSurfaceShading(model) {
        if (!this.dataView) {
            return;
        }

        const devices = [];
        const structureInfo = new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(model);
        const types = Array.from(this.dataView.getChannels().keys());

        for (const [sensorId, sensor] of this.dataView.getSensors().entries()) {
            if (!sensor.objectId) {
                continue;
            }

            devices.push({
                id: sensorId,
                dbId: sensor.objectId,
                position: sensor.location,
                name: sensor.name,
                sensorTypes: types.concat()
            });
        }

        // Generates `SurfaceShadingData` after assigning each device to a room.
        let nodeName = 'Rooms';
        const levels = await structureInfo.getLevelRoomsMap(false, nodeName);
        await structureInfo.mapDevicesInRoom(devices, nodeName);

        // Resolve Room collision issue to avoid incorrect devise mapping.
        /**
         *  ----------------
         * |                |
         * |                |
         * |      Room 1    |
         * |        ________|
         * |       | Room 2 |
         *  -----------------
         */
        let roomsWithoutDevice = structureInfo.rooms.filter(r => r.devices.length <= 0);
        for (let i = 0; i < roomsWithoutDevice.length; i++) {
            let room = roomsWithoutDevice[i];
            let collision = structureInfo.rooms.find(r => r.bounds.containsBox(room.bounds));

            for (let j = 0; j < collision.devices.length; j++) {
                let device = collision.devices[j];

                if ((!room.devices.includes(device)) && (structureInfo.roomGeomContainsPoint(room, device.position))) {
                    // Build bi-directional references
                    device.roomId = room.id;
                    room.addDevice(device);

                    collision.devices.splice(j, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        const shadingData = await structureInfo.generateSurfaceShadingData(devices, levels, nodeName);
        this._surfaceShadingData = shadingData;

        // Use the resulting shading data to generate heatmap from.
        await this._dataVizExt.setupSurfaceShading(model, shadingData);

        // Register color stops for the heatmap. Along with the normalized sensor value
        // in the range of [0.0, 1.0], `renderSurfaceShading` will interpolate the final
        // heatmap color based on these specified colors.
        // const sensorColors = [0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0xffff00, 0xff0000];
        // types.map(sensorType => this._dataVizExt.registerSurfaceShadingColors(sensorType, sensorColors));
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It works with your provided codes. Thank you again!

Comment: There is a new problem. Three of four rooms have been rendered successfully. However, there is a room that is not rendered. What should I do to address this issue? The room area is only 12 m2, others are more than 90 m2, will this influence?

Comment: The room is in white color stripes. The Room can be checked in Model Browser in Viewer, and the sensor-4 is within the fourth room.

Comment: I noticed that, but the original implementation in the sample should also work for your model. Please kindly check configs.js on your side. I provided my test case via APS Help.

Comment: If you really want to use the default way by `ModelStructureInfo`, you must do some extra device-room mapping, since one room is inside another. Please check the above.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You are right, the room with white color stripes is inside another room. Maybe this led to the render failure.